# Причина удаления "Этот ответ-ссылка (а не спам)" звучит не по-русски

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

> [image: Этот ответ-ссылка (а не спам)]

Во-первых, тут явная опечатка в первом слове. Ни разу не слышал чтобы так говорили.

Во-вторых, союз "а" подразумевает, что тут должен быть спам, но вместо него написали ответ-ссылку. Чтобы исключить спамовые ответы из этой причины для удаления - лучше использовать союз "но".

Варианты перевода - в ответах.

---

Оригинал: [Tx:958](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/40262630?key=343c259ccfc4e88458ceb9917da5050f)

> This is a link-only answer (and not spam)

Comment: просто пробелы надо поставить и дефис превратиться в тире - станет выглядеть норм

Comment: @Grundy эээ... А тире-то тут на кой?

Comment: Союз "а" тут как раз в значении "но" и употреблен. Типа в ответе есть ссылка, но это не ссылка нормальная, а не спам

Comment: ну как же: Этот ответ - ссылка, а не спам.

Comment: @Grundy так еще хуже

Comment: @Grundy если написать как вы предлагаете - то получится смысл "причина удаления: этот ответ не является спамом". Совершенно не то, что имелось в виду.

Comment: По идее, в скобках нужно просто "не спам", а иначе, если есть союзы, хоть "а", хоть "но", то нужно ставить запятую перед ними. Мне кажется, что лучший вариант: "Это ответ-ссылка (не спам)".

Comment: @PavelMayorov, не-не, там получается что удаляется потому что этот ответ ссылка, но не спам, а какая-то другая:)

Comment: Пожалуйста, вынесите предложенный вариант в отдельный ответ. Таким образом мы сможем разделить голосование за перевод от самой инициативы.

Comment: Тире вид портит

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky Перевод стал точнее, но предлагаю не помечать вопрос как завершённый и продолжить работу.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky вы тут отметили задачу как завершённую, но в Transifex осталась старая строка...

Comment: @NickVolynkin  На самом деле, все было обновлено в соответствии с [лучшим ответом](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/3228/6) на тот момент.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky возможно, я просмотрел. Мне показалось, что изменений не было.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Зачем вообще упоминать про (не)спам? Почему бы не переформулировать более радикально, например:

> Ссылка на ответ вместо самого ответа

Comment: А хороший вариант, кстати.

Comment: Наконец-то нормальная русская фраза. И смысл передаёт точно.

Comment: Только что применил этот вариант.

Answer (score 2):

Предлагаю вариант: *"**Это** ответ-ссылка (**но** не спам)"*

Comment: Получился подстрочник. Он точнее того, что было, но давайте пойдём дальше. Русскому переводу не обязательно сохранять структуру английского языка.

Answer (score 1):

Ещё одна вариация:

***Это** ответ-ссылка (**хотя и** не спам).*

Comment: _"Хотя"?_ Т. е. мы сожалеем, что это не спам?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Мы удаляем его, потому что это ответ-ссылка (хотя и не спам-ссылка, да).

Answer (score 1):

Вариант "Это ответ-ссылка (не спам)".

В скобках сухая констатация факта. Иначе, если используются союзы, то очевидна незаконченность предложения и появляется желание добавить что-нибудь из ряда "а/но не спам, к сожалению", "а/но не спам, ехууу!" и пару смайлов в нагрузку.

Comment: "но" ничем не мешает.

Comment: @Qwertiy, если предложение стремится быть безапелляционным утверждением, что ответ является ссылкой, то добавление исключения в виде союза "но" отнюдь не прибавляет веса этой самой безапелляционности, даже не смотря на то, что по смыслу призвано её подтвердить с уточнением деталей (наличие скобок). Разумеется, это субъективное чувство главного посыла в утверждении, каким оно должно быть. И конечно попытки юлить (а союзы это всегда обход острых углов (вот как сейчас :) ) на мой взгляд неуместны в данной ситуации.

Answer (score -4):

(вариант от Grundy)

Достаточно заменить на тире: *"Этот ответ — ссылка (а не спам)"*

Answer (score -4):

Ничего не надо делать, и так понятно: *"Этот ответ-ссылка (а не спам)"*

Answer (score -5):

<sub>**Этот ответ не спам, а ссылка**</sub>

Comment: Можно убрать местоимение *Этот*. **Ответ – не спам, а ссылка**

Comment: Опять удаляем ответ потому что это не спам?..

Comment: @PavelMayorov, где написано что мы его опять удаляем? Это пометка сообщения, что это не спам, а дальше конкретизируем что это есть ссылка

Comment: @PavelMayorov, исходя из заголовка вопроса "*Этот ответ-ссылка (а не спам)*", самое главое пометить ответ, что он не является спамом. Уберём обозначение, останется **Этот ответ не спам**.

Comment: [мог ел](https://pp.vk.me/c630025/v630025313/378ac/gU1sPsH-A-g.jpg) Сразу видно, что с русским туго. Лишь бы заминусить не подумав. Как ты пришёл к выводу, что "*опять удаляем*" вообще не пойму

Comment: мы вообще-то причину удаления обсуждаем

Comment: @PavelMayorov, Наименование причины, а не причину. Не русский чтоли или меня в заблуждение вводишь?

Comment: @Doofy, русский - это прежде всего состояние души. Вежливость является его неотъемлемой частью, поскольку с чего бы не быть вежливым, если прав и сильный. Спам-ответ может быть просто в виде ссылки, а у Вас получается взаимоисключение. Плюс, придётся менять (сочинять новое) описание к причине удаления, так как текущее относится лишь к ответу-ссылке, никак не касаясь спама.

Comment: @alexis031182, я не стану здесь обсуждать проблемы, не касающиеся темы. К Павлуше имею личную неприязнь, по повду его поведения в прошлом. Если тут заправляют слабоумные, которым плюсуют из-за их репутации, тогда мне здесь делать нечего